# Replace personal names and addresses with company ones

Tags: python, design-patterns, pandas, vectorization

### The problem:

I am given a data frame. Somewhere in that dataframe there is 3*N
number of columns that I need to modify based on a condition. The
columns of interest look like this:

| names_1 | address_1 | description_1 | names_2 | address_2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | joe_address | ... | George | ... | ... |
| Kate | kate_address | ... | Daphne | ... | ... |
| Bob | bob_address | ... | Jake | ... | ... |

I can generate this with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

names_dict = {'names_1':['Joe', 'Kate', 'Bob'],
              'address_1':['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
              'description_1':['d1', 'd2', 'd3'],
              'names_2':['George', 'Daphne', 'Jake'],
              'address_2':['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
              'description_2':['d4', 'd5', 'd6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=names_dict)
```

There is also a dictionary that I need to use. The keys to that
dictionary are names of some companies. Each key has a list of names
attached. It looks like this:

```
companies_dict = {'company1': ['Kate', 'Mark', 'Ben'],
                  'company2':['Jacob', 'Michael', 'Ken'],
                  'company3':['Jake', 'Don', 'Joe']}
```

I need to go over all `names_k` columns. If I encounter a
name that is in one of the companies lists, I swap the name of that
person with the name of that company. Moreover, I swap the address
and description of that person with the address and the description of
that company.

Here are dictionaries to use for this purpose:

```
companies_descriptions = {'company1': 'company1_desc',
                          'company2': 'company2_desc',
                          'company3': 'company3_desc'}
companies_addresses = {'company1': 'company1_address',
                       'company2': 'company2_address',
                       'company3': 'company3_address'}
```

Note:  The columns are somewhere in the dataframe, but they are next
to each other. That is, the `names_1` all the way to `description_N`
are next to each other.

### My solution:

I wrote the following Python code.

```
N = 2
number_of_columns = N
for k in range(1, number_of_columns+1):
  for index, name in enumerate(df[f'names_{k}']):
    for company, name_list in companies_dict.items():
      if name in name_list:
        df.loc[index, f'names_{k}'] = company
        df.loc[index, f'address_{k}'] = companies_descriptions.get(company)
        df.loc[index, f'description_{k}'] = companies_addresses.get(company)
```

Note:

1. We can safely assume that each person's name is
   unique. So no two companies have the same employee.
2. N = 2 is an arbitrary value. Should work for any int>=1. It dictates how many columns (named names_k) there are and is defined by a separate process. N = 2 is given here as an example.

My solution is ugly, but it solves the problem. **How to write it better?**

Here is the whole code to copy:

```
import pandas as pd

names_dict = {'names_1':['Joe', 'Kate', 'Bob'],
              'address_1':['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
              'description_1':['d1', 'd2', 'd3'],
              'names_2':['George', 'Daphne', 'Jake'],
              'address_2':['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
              'description_2':['d4', 'd5', 'd6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=names_dict)
companies_dict = {'company1': ['Kate', 'Mark', 'Ben'],
                  'company2':['Jacob', 'Michael', 'Ken'],
                  'company3':['Jake', 'Don', 'Joe']}
companies_descriptions = {'company1': 'company1_desc',
                          'company2': 'company2_desc',
                          'company3': 'company3_desc'}
companies_addresses = {'company1': 'company1_address',
                       'company2': 'company2_address',
                       'company3': 'company3_address'}

N = 2
number_of_columns = N
for k in range(1, number_of_columns+1):
  for index, name in enumerate(df[f'names_{k}']):
    for company, name_list in companies_dict.items():
      if name in name_list:
        df.loc[index, f'names_{k}'] = company
        df.loc[index, f'address_{k}'] = companies_descriptions.get(company)
        df.loc[index, f'description_{k}'] = companies_addresses.get(company)
```

Comment: And what should happen when two different companies' employees have the same name?  That does happen, frequently.

Comment: Yes, that latest edit has improved the question.  It looks complete now.  Thanks for responding positively.

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question? Either way, please tag it as such

Comment: It's neither of those two

Comment: You wrote the problem statement as a quote but it seems like it's not actually a quote.

Comment: I did not write the problem statement as a quote. It was changed by someone else. For the more aesthetic formatting I believe. I've described the whole problem myself.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Then I'm going to remove those quotes.

Comment: The person ("you") in the problem statement was confusing and made it seem like a homework problem, so I have changed it to the first person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The question

It's unhelpful, in a handful of ways:

- It presents you data that are shaped in an unhelpful way
- It implies the use of non-vectorised dictionary lookups
- It implies the use of non-vectorised iteration
- What you're really doing is building up a dataframe of merged *contacts*, but the question does not describe this

Since you claim this is not from a course, and from your own scenario, this is somewhat an x/y problem: you asked how to do x when you shouldn't do x at all, and should do y instead.

### The existing code

Get rid of all of your `for`-loops. Get rid of all of your dictionary lookups. Get rid of element-wise reassignment.

### Vectorised approach

You've tagged your question `vectorization`, but the language of the problem statement is not guiding you toward this, and your own solution (perhaps unsurprisingly) is not vectorised - but it should be.

This will be done in, roughly, the following steps:

- Fix the broken column representation in the first dataframe
- Load the other dictionaries into dataframes with sensible indices and columns
- Left-merge to get a porous merged-dataframe
- `fillna` to substite where possible

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd

# You are given a data frame. Somewhere in that dataframe there is 3*N number of columns
contacts: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    'names_1': ('Joe', 'Kate', 'Bob'),
    'address_1': ('a1', 'a2', 'a3'),
    'description_1': ('d1', 'd2', 'd3'),
    'names_2': ('George', 'Daphne', 'Jake'),
    'address_2': ('a4', 'a5', 'a6'),
    'description_2': ('d4', 'd5', 'd6'),
})
contacts.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    contacts.columns.str.extract(r'(.+)_(\d+)$'),
    names=('property', 'contact_group'),
)
contacts.index.name = 'contact'

# There is also a dictionary that you need to use. The keys to that dictionary
# are names of some companies. Each key has a list of names attached.
companies_dict = {
    'company1': ('Kate', 'Mark', 'Ben'),
    'company2': ('Jacob', 'Michael', 'Ken'),
    'company3': ('Jake', 'Don', 'Joe'),
}
company_employees: pd.Series = pd.DataFrame(companies_dict).stack()
company_employees.index.names = 'employee', 'company_name'
company_employees.name = 'employee_name'

# you swap the address and description of that person with the address and the
# description of that company. Here are dictionaries to use for this purpose:
companies_descriptions = {
    'company1': 'company1_desc',
    'company2': 'company2_desc',
    'company3': 'company3_desc',
}
companies_addresses = {
    'company1': 'company1_address',
    'company2': 'company2_address',
    'company3': 'company3_address',
}
companies = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'description': companies_descriptions,
    'address': companies_addresses,
})
companies.index.name = 'company_name'

# You need to iterate over all [employee] names_k columns. If you encounter an [employee] name that
# is in one of the companies lists, you swap the name of that person with the name of that company.
# Moreover, you swap the address and description of that person with the address and the description
# of that company.

employees_with_company_properties = pd.merge(
    left=company_employees, right=companies,
    left_on='company_name', right_on='company_name'
)
contacts_long = contacts.stack(level='contact_group')
contacts_merged = pd.merge(
    left=contacts_long, right=employees_with_company_properties.reset_index(),
    left_on='names', right_on='employee_name',
    suffixes=('_employee', '_company'),
    how='left',
).set_index(contacts_long.index)

contacts_replaced = contacts_merged[[
    'company_name', 'address_company', 'description_company'
]].rename(columns={
    'company_name': 'names',
    'address_company': 'address',
    'description_company': 'description',
}).fillna(
    contacts_merged[['names', 'address_employee', 'description_employee']]
    .rename(columns={
        'address_employee': 'address',
        'description_employee': 'description',
    })
).unstack(
    level='contact_group'
).sort_values('contact_group', axis=1)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(contacts_replaced)
```

### Output

```
                  names           address    description     names           address    description
contact_group         1                 1              1         2                 2              2
contact                                                                                            
0              company3  company3_address  company3_desc    George                a4             d4
1              company1  company1_address  company1_desc    Daphne                a5             d5
2                   Bob                a3             d3  company3  company3_address  company3_desc
```

Comment: Thanks, nice data manipulation :D. "It implies the use of non-vectorised iteration" - yes, that was unfortunate, I'll change that now. The only issue I have with this solution is that the idea of what we are trying to do is not quite clear as we read the code. But I suppose that's due to the amount of changes you had to make to the structure of the data. Do you agree?

Comment: Re. _I'll change that now_ - either it is a quote, in which case you shouldn't change it, or it's not actually a quote.

Comment: Re. clarity - I mostly disagree. Whereas vectorisation can make the code longer and more difficult to understand for people unfamiliar with Pandas, once you understand the individual calls, the whole is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting the loop, we should probably invert the employees list, so that we have a dict that maps each employee to their company:

```
employers = { name: co for co,names in companies_dict.items() for name in names }
```

That eliminates the inner loop, and replaces with a simple `dict.get()`, so improving the code's scalability.

It's not clear where `N = 2` comes from, as that's not mentioned in the extract of the problem statement.  Could be worth a comment.  Or perhaps we should change the code to work with any number of replacements - surely we just need to go up to ⅓ the number of columns?

```
max_k = len(df.columns) // 3
```

Or forget about `N` and after `name_1` just keep incrementing `k` until there's no `name_k` column.

Indexing using `.iloc` is much more efficient than `enumerate(df[f'names_{k}'])`, and we're told about the columns' order, so we can use that information:

```
col = df.columns.get_loc('names_1')
colgroup = 1
while col < len(df.columns) and df.columns[col] == f'names_{colgroup}':
    for row_index in range(len(df)):
        company = employers.get(df.iloc[row_index, col])
        if company:
            df.iloc[row_index, col] = company
            df.iloc[row_index, col+1] = companies_descriptions.get(company)
            df.iloc[row_index, col+2] = companies_addresses.get(company)
    colgroup += 1
    col += 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by the last statement. There are 3*N columns. That's because there are N columns such as names_k. Each names_k column has corresponding address and description column.

Comment: If there are 3*N columns or more but we are not given N, then we can deduce an upper bound for N: it's not more than (columns/3).  That's all.

Comment: Yes, we don't use the guarantee that the columns are consecutive. However, we can use this guarantee, but I don't see how to do that exactly. I also don't see how inverting the companies_dict helps.

Comment: Inverting the dict turns the lookup from a linear search (`for company, name_list in companies_dict.items(): if name in name_list:`) into a simple dict access (`company = employer[name]`).

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, it is clearer for me now. What do you think, which solution is more readable? Mine or yours? That's what I value the most here.

Comment: I think both could be improved, but mine's slightly ahead with `employers.get()` instead of another level of looping (somewhat masked by your non-standard indent of 2 spaces per level; PEP-8 recommends 4).

Comment: This approach is somewhat of a non-starter and does not use Pandas as it was intended (though, to be fair, the question is misleading and implies an iterative approach).

Comment: Also note: OP tagged their question `vectorization`